# Как правильно составить SQL запрос с пустым полем

Tags: mysql, sql

В базе имеются 2 таблицы: document и yc(справочник).
В таблице document есть поле необязательное для заполнения id_yc, связанное с ключевым полем таблицы yc. При попытке составления запроса вывода для таблицы document, выводятся только те записи, где поле id_yc не пустое. Как сделать так, чтобы выводились все записи, а не только с не пустым полем?

```
SELECT
  n_doc,
  naim_doc,
  route_to_papka,
  YC_kol_vo_list,
  YC_data_sost,
  YC_data_otpr,
  yc.naim_yc
FROM doc,
     yc
WHERE (yc.id_yc = doc.id_yc);
```

Comment: приведите текст запроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT
  n_doc,
  naim_doc,
  route_to_papka,
  YC_kol_vo_list,
  YC_data_sost,
  YC_data_otpr,
  yc.naim_yc
FROM doc,
     yc
WHERE (yc.id_yc = doc.id_yc OR doc.id_yc is NULL OR doc.id_yc='');
```

Comment: `yc.id_yc = NULL`  это ж ключевое поле

Comment: В таблице document есть поле необязательное для заполнения id_yc

Comment: `В таблице document`

Comment: счас исправим :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  n_doc,
  naim_doc,
  route_to_papka,
  YC_kol_vo_list,
  YC_data_sost,
  YC_data_otpr,
  yc.naim_yc
FROM doc
  LEFT JOIN  -- <--
     yc
**ON** yc.id_yc = doc.id_yc;
```

Comment: Да, сорри, поспешил)
Исправил

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено

```
SELECT
  distinct(n_doc),
  naim_doc,
  route_to_papka,
  YC_kol_vo_list,
  YC_data_sost,
  YC_data_otpr,
  yc.naim_yc
FROM doc,
     yc
WHERE (yc.id_yc = doc.id_yc or doc.id_yc is null);
```